# Select a specific row of a datatable on load

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatable

I try to use datatables in my view (see [Datatables)](https://datatables.net/)

My problem is that I want to select a specific row that contains a value.
For example if there is a table including one column and two rows and the forst cell includes "first" and the second "second", I want to iterate and if I find the value "second" I want to select this row.

What I tried is:

```
table.column(0).data().each(function (value, index) {
        if (value == 'second') {
            table.row(index).addClass('selected');
        }
    });
```

and

```
table.rows().indexes().each(function (i) {
        var r = table.row(i);
        if (r.data().category == 'second') {
            r.node().to$().addClass("active");
        }
    });
```

and

```
table.rows().each(function (i) {
        var r = table.row(i);
        if ($(this).text() == 'second') {
            alert('test');
            r.node().to$().addClass("active");
        }
    });
```

all of them with no results, nothing happens.

Do you have any idea how I can do this? I would be very thankful for any suggestion.

Comment: Check out the jQuery docs for .each iterator. 
https://api.jquery.com/each/

The value that you are looking for is actually .text() on the $(this) within each iteration.

Comment: I don't know how to select a row, the specific command.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to check if the row contains the value at binding (RowDataBound event), and select it (set .SelectedIndex property to the row index). Assuming you are using gridview, anyway

Comment: I don't know what RowDataBound is. I include some jquery files and build a html table and after this it is selectable. But I don't know how to find a specific row and select it. I'm able to select the first row but not a specific

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add following jquery script :

Here '#example' is id of datatable.

```
$('#example td').each(function() {
        var cellText = $(this).html();    

        if(cellText == 'second'){
         $(this).closest('tr').addClass("selected");
        }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ebRXw/539/)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are trying to add a class only on the specific row. You can try my code below:

```
rowCallback: function (row, data) {
                            if (something == true) {
                                table.row(row).select()
                            }
                        },
```

rowCallback function allows you to 'post process' each row after it have been generated for each table draw, but before it is rendered into the document. This means that the contents of the row might not have dimensions ($().width() for example) if it is not already in the document.([1](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback))